# collect content from multiple lines into one single output

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, newlines

assume I have a text file with lots of content including lines like these:

```
...    
...
ABCD1 1234 12345
XYZ
foo bar 1234597890
...
DEFG2 5678 56789
XYZ
foo bar 0987654321
...
...
```

and I need to extract find the data sequrnce by using `grep -C1 "XYZ"`.
Now what I need to do is, to assemble output that looks something like:

```
ABCD1 1234567890 12345 1234
DEFG2 0987654321 56789 5678
```

I know that I can use `grep -z "XYZ"` to get rid of the line "I don't care about" and use `awk` to extract data from a line to assemble it in the way I want. but what I'm missing is: How can I remove the `/n` fom one line before my `grep` plus at the line of the `grep` match? so that I can pipe the data on one singe line to `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more elegant to do the whole thing in `awk`, but if you want something quick and dirty then you can just set the `awk` record separator equal to the `grep` group separator - and then print the whitespace-delimited fields that you want in the order that you want:

```
grep -C1 XYZ file | awk -vRS='\n--' '{print $1, $NF, $3, $2}'
ABCD1 1234597890 12345 1234
DEFG2 0987654321 56789 5678
```